# Why is email not being sent with ActiveJob?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sidekiq

I'm in the process of upgrading an app to Rails 4.2 so we can take advantage of the ActionMailer's `deliver_later` method. Everything is working great in development. When I deploy to our staging server using the `capistrano-sidekiq` gem, emails don't appear to be delivered. Based on this log, it appears the job is queued and executed properly.

Server is Ubuntu 14.04 with redis installed via apt-get.

```
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActionMailer::DeliveryJob (Job ID: 51ddade2-4689-40fd-aeda-7e94f7260e43) to Sidekiq(mailers) with arguments: 
"ApplicationMailer", "admin_message", "deliver_now", "Broken Link", "Testing an email from staging."
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [51ddade2-4689-40fd-aeda-7e94f7260e43] Performing ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Sidekiq(mailers) 
with arguments: "ApplicationMailer", "admin_message", "deliver_now", "Broken Link", "Testing an email from staging."
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [51ddade2-4689-40fd-aeda-7e94f7260e43]   Rendered application_mailer/admin_message.html.erb within  layouts/mailer (1.9ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [51ddade2-4689-40fd-aeda-7e94f7260e43]   Rendered layouts/mailer.html.erb (8.8ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [51ddade2-4689-40fd-aeda-7e94f7260e43]   Rendered application_mailer/admin_message.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.8ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [51ddade2-4689-40fd-aeda-7e94f7260e43]   Rendered layouts/mailer.text.erb (3.6ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [51ddade2-4689-40fd-aeda-7e94f7260e43]
Sent mail to email-testing@loamstudios.com (216.8ms)
[ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [51ddade2-4689-40fd-aeda-7e94f7260e43] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Sidekiq(mailers) in 796.8ms
```

I checked to see if sidekiq was running using `ps aux | [sS]idekiq` and there is an entry:

```
deploy   15104  0.4  7.4 972692 152452 ?       Sl   10:07   0:03 sidekiq 3.5.1 sustainabilityassessment_staging [0 of 25 busy]
```

I also ensured the mailers queue exists with `set :sidekiq_queue, ["default", "mailers"]` in my `deploy.rb`.

My mailer method:

```
def admin_message(subject, message)
    @message = message
    mail(to: "<address>", subject: subject)
  end
```

Any idea what's going on or what I can troubleshoot next?

Edit:
Did some more digging. I started sidekiq using `RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec sidekiq -q mailers -q default` in the `appname/current` and tried sending the emails again. This time the emails sent, so there appears to be something wrong with the way the capistrano-sidekiq gem starts sidekiq.

Edit:
Setup sidekiq's monitoring application to see if I could learn anything new. It appears jobs are being processed without issue. Still am not receiving email...

Edit: Discovered an extra `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false` in `config/environments/staging.rb` that was blocking me from seeing my errors. I can now see emails are being rejected:

```
Net::SMTPServerBusy: 454 4.7.1 <email address>: Relay access denied
```

Edit: One more piece of information, calling `deliver_now` on the same mailer works. Calling `deliver_later` causes the emails to be rejected. This leads me to think the SMTP settings for the app are working. Something is happening in the `deliver_later` call to prevent the email from being sent.

Comment: Make sure you have `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` in your Rails' config. That'll help you troubleshoot if ActionMailer is encountering errors.

Comment: Thanks. Added the line. Tested. No such luck. Same log entries.

Comment: Does the email send successfully when you use `deliver_now`? That'll help narrow down whether its a configuration issue or a sidekiq problem.

Comment: `deliver_now` works.

Comment: Would you mind posting the content of your mailer method? I noticed that using ActiveJob causes [mailer methods to be executed twice](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/21220#issuecomment-131658705).  Is there any chance that your mailer method would behave differently when executed a second time?

Comment: @Ben Add mailer method. I don't think it would...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently on one of our servers. It was configured exactly the same way as another server, but emails weren't being sent, even though it looked like Resque was successfully processing them.

It turned out to be an issue with [God](http://godrb.com/), our monitoring tool. Running `sudo service god restart` by itself did not properly reset the workers. The solution was to stop all workers with `sudo god stop`, verify that they were stopped with `ps aux | grep resque`, then shutdown god with `sudo service god stop` and start it with `sudo service god start`.

If you're using some kind of tool to monitor, start, and stop Sidekiq, I would look into that and make sure the workers are properly stopped and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. This fixed it:

Inside config/deploy.rb:

```
set :sidekiq_queue, "mailers"
```

Apparently, ActiveJob sends the job to the 'mailers' queue, but the sidekiq gem only creates the default and notifications queues if not specified in the configuration.

Comment: I have `set :sidekiq_queue, ["default", "mailers"]` in config/deploy.rb